# How to concatenate an input and a matrix in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am building a model in Keras. I have an input

```
X = Input(shape=(input_size, ), name='input_feature')
```

and a fixed pre-given numpy matrix `D` which is `input_size` by `n`.

I want to concatenate X and D before input them to the next layer. In other word, I need to concatenate each slice of X and D to generate a new inpt whose expected size should be `(none, input_size, n+1)`. So what should I do to concatenate them? In my understanding, the batch size is `none` since it will adaptive to the batch size of input X when we fit data to the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer if D has shape (batch, input_size,n)

Provided that D is a tensor (it's a tensor if it's an output from some layer):

```
X = Reshape((input_size,1))(X)
concat = Concatenate()([D,X])
```

If D is not a tensor:

```
import keras.backend as K

#create a tensor:
Dval = K.variable(numpyArrayForD)

#create an input for D:
D = Input(tensor=Dval)

#do as in the top of this answer.
```

---

If you want to avoid the additional `Input` (it will not affect the way you train, because of the `tensor` parameter), you can use a lambda layer:

```
def concatenation(x):
    D = K.variable(D_df)

    return K.concatenate([x,D])

XD = Lambda(concatenation,output_shape=(input_size,n+1))(X)
```

#### Answer if D has shape (input_size,n)

In this case, it's probably better replicate D many times. You can do this outside of the model, using numpy functions before creating the `K.variable` (see the other answer), like this:

```
D_df = D_df.reshape((1,input_size,n))
D_df = numpy.repeat(D_df,batch,axis=0)
```

But this approach requires you to adapt to the size of x beforehand. 
If you want something that adapts to any size of X without having to change D before, then it's more complicated....

Comment: Thank you. Actually D is a pre-given pandas dataframe with shape(input_size, n). Suppose this dataframe is called `D_df`. Is it correct to use `Dval = K.variable(D_df)` to create a tensor. And use `D = Input(tensor=Dval)` and `XD = merge([X, D, ], mode='concat')` to concatenate them?

Comment: If `K.variable` can handle that format, yes... if not, convert pandas to numpy. But I suggest you use the `Concatenate` layer as in my answer. It's documented, while this `merge` seems not to be the recommended way.

Comment: Since `D_df` is pre-given, do I still need to use `D=Input(tensor=Dval)` to convert it to an input? Or just `concat = Concatenate()([X,Dval])`? The reason I am asking this is actually we only have one input which is X.

Comment: Yes, unless you put it inside a lambda layer. It's equivalent, but it needs to be a tensor (from `K.variable`), it cannot be a pandas object. This approach of creating `Input(tensor=)` will not demand an additional input in `compile` or in `fit`.

Comment: `ValueError: 'Concatenate' layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 4214, 1), (4214, 22311)]` It seems something wrong, when I use `concat = concatnate([X,D])`

Comment: Oh, that means that `D` is not `(batch, input_size, n)`. It is only `(input_size,n)`. While `X` is `(batch, input_size,1)`. Is this true? -- If so, it's not possible to concatenate them.

Comment: Yes. `D` is converted from numpy arrary whose shape is `(4214, 22311)`.

Comment: Then it's simply not possible. Both must have 3 dimensions, and 2 of these dimensions must be equal.

Comment: What I want to do is for each slice in the batch, we concatenate D and X. Maybe I can first extend D to (batch, input_size, n) tensor, for example make copies of D to each slice?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154932/discussion-between-daniel-moller-and-wedoso).